# PHP: Sort array by value length

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array by the length of characters in each value (and perhaps, if possible, in alphabetical order if two values have the same length of characters). For example:

```
Array ( [0] => this [1] => is [2] => a [3] => bunch [4] => of [5] => words;
```

I am trying to sort this array to look like:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => is [2] => of [3] => this [4] => bunch [5] => words;
```

How?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should do it:

```
array_multisort(array_map('strlen', $array), $array);
```

- Get the length of each string in an array by mapping `strlen()` using `array_map()`
- Sort on the string lengths and sort the original array by the string length sorted array using `array_multisort()`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like others have already answered but I started writing this so I'm going to post it, dang it! :)

You could take a look at [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
$data = ["this", "is", "a", "bunch", "of", "words"];

usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    $difference =  strlen($a) - strlen($b);

    return $difference ?: strcmp($a, $b);
});
```

I'm using the Elvis operator `?:` to just return the difference based on the string lengths if it's not 0. If it is 0, just return the return value of `strcmp`

Comment: you get +1 since I learned what's the *Elvis operator* in PHP :p.

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```
$myarray = explode(" ", "this is a bunch of words");
usort($myarray, function($a, $b) { return strlen($a) - strlen($b) });
print_r($array);
```

Explanation: `usort` sorts **in place** (i.e. by reference) an array, given a custom comparator. A comparator must return a negative number if the first item should be before the second item, and a positive otherwise. A value of 0 means they are equal regarding the order.

You can add custom criteria, not related to strlen() when the lengths are the same. That's up to you and involves just an additional `if` block.

**It is important** to note that the function must define an order relationship, as in math:

1. criteria(a, b)>0 and criteria(b, c)>0 implies criteria(a, c)>0.
2. the same applies to the lower-than sign, lower-than-or-equal, greater-than-or-equal, and equal.
3. criteria(a, b) should have an opposite sign of criteria(b, a).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom sort function for this.

```
function mycmp($a, $b) {
    $cmp = strlen($a) - strlen($b);
    if ($cmp === 0)
        $cmp = strcmp($a, $b);
    return $cmp;
}

usort($array, 'mycmp');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```php
$f = fn($s1, $s2) => strlen($s1) <=> strlen($s2);
usort($a, $f);
```

https://php.net/language.operators.comparison